# How to access the Project from other project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I know how to add the project as module in another project and how to use that.

```
Project_A
 ---gradle
 ---build
 ---settings.gradle
 ---project_a
     ---build
     ---src
     ---lib
     ---build.gradle
 ---project_b(LibraryProject)
     ---build
     ---src
     ---lib
     ---build.gradle
```

In settings.gradle

```
 include ':project_a', ':project_b'
```

In build.gradle(Module:project_a)

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':project_b')
}
```

This is working fine. Now I can access the project_b properties in my project_a.

Now I am trying to add the module from out side of the project folder. Is it possible to refer the project_b without add as module to project_a.
I have create project_b seperatly and kept out of project_a. I want to access the project_b from project_a. Is it possible. In other terms like add library from git/maven/jcenter.

```
Project_A
 ---gradle
 ---build
 ---settings.gradle

Project_B(LibraryProject)
 ---gradle
 ---build
 ---settings.gradle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of a module is not necessary. If you define its path correctly at your `settings.gradle` file you can use it.

For instance, let your `project_b` module is under `Project_B` project and your `Project_A` and `Project_B` directories are at the same workspace:

```
- Workspace
  - Project_A
    - project_a
  - Project_B
    - project_b
```

At the `settings.gradle` file of `Project_A` you should define its path:

```
include ':project_b'
project(':project_b').projectDir = new File("../Project_B/project_b")
```

**Note:** You can also set the absolute path (i.e. C://WorkSpace/Project_B/project_b) at settings.gradle.

Comment: Hi. I will try this and let you know soon..!!

Comment: I am getting this error. `Error:(29, 0) Cannot set the value of read-only property 'projectDir' for project ':project_b' of type org.gradle.api.Project.` Any idea to resolve this?